# iter, values, item in dictionary does not work

Tags: python, dictionary

Having this python code

```
edges = [(0, [3]), (1, [0]), (2, [1, 6]), (3, [2]), (4, [2]), (5, [4]), (6, [5, 8]), (7, [9]), (8, [7]), (9, [6])]
graph = {0: [3], 1: [0], 2: [1, 6], 3: [2], 4: [2], 5: [4], 6: [5, 8], 7: [9], 8: [7], 9: [6]}
cycles = {}
while graph:
    current = graph.iteritems().next()
    cycle = [current]
    cycles[current] = cycle
    while current in graph:
        next = graph[current][0]
        del graph[current][0]
        if len(graph[current]) == 0:
            del graph[current]
        current = next
        cycle.append(next)


def traverse(tree, root):
    out = []
    for r in tree[root]:
        if r != root and r in tree:
            out += traverse(tree, r)
        else:
            out.append(r)
    return out

print ('->'.join([str(i) for i in traverse(cycles, 0)]))



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\E\Desktop\c.py", line 20, in <module>
    current = graph.iteritems().next()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I also tried itervalues, iterkeys... but that does not work
How to modify code?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are using Python 3; use `dict.items()` instead.

The Python 2 `dict.iter*` methods have been renamed in Python 3, where `dict.items()` returns a dictionary view instead of a list by default now. Dictionary views act as iterables in the same way `dict.iteritems()` do in Python 2.

From the [Python 3 What's New documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists):

> - `dict` methods `dict.keys()`, `dict.items()` and `dict.values()` return “views” instead of lists. For example, this no longer works: `k = d.keys(); k.sort()`. Use `k = sorted(d)` instead (this works in Python 2.5 too and is just as efficient).
> - Also, the `dict.iterkeys()`, `dict.iteritems()` and `dict.itervalues()` methods are no longer supported.

Also, the `.next()` method has been renamed to `.__next__()`, but dictionary views are not iterators. The line `graph.iteritems().next()` would have to be translated instead, to:

```
current = next(iter(graph.items()))
```

which uses `iter()` to turn the items view into an iterable and `next()` to get the next value from that iterable.

You'll also have to rename the `next` variable in the `while` loop; using that replaces the built-in `next()` function which you need here. Use `next_` instead.

The next problem is that you are trying to use `current` as a key in `cycles`, but `current` is a tuple of an integer and a *list* of integers, making the whole value not hashable. I *think* you wanted to get just the next *key* instead, in which case `next(iter(dict))` would give you that:

```
while graph:
    current = next(iter(graph))
    cycle = [current]
    cycles[current] = cycle
    while current in graph:
        next_ = graph[current][0]
        del graph[current][0]
        if len(graph[current]) == 0:
            del graph[current]
        current = next_
        cycle.append(next_)
```

This then produces some output:

```
>>> cycles
{0: [0, 3, 2, 1, 0], 2: [2, 6, 5, 4, 2], 6: [6, 8, 7, 9, 6]}
```

Comment: I have changed dict.iteritems to dict.items and now I get Traceback   `File "C:\Users\E\Desktop\c.py", line 18, in <module>
    current = graph.items().next()
AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'next'`

Comment: Should I use a for loop or something instead `.next()` ?

Comment: @cMinor: did this code work in Python 2 at all? You are trying to use a tuple containing a list as a key in `current`. That means it is not hashable, that is not allowed in Python 2 *or* 3.

Comment: @cMinor: Did you perhaps meant to make `current` just the next *key* instead the next key/value pair?