# Casting a dictionary as a list causes problems

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax, python-3.3

I'm working on making an Euilerian Cycle. 
(the same program as this person here:
[iter, values, item in dictionary does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444340/iter-values-item-in-dictionary-does-not-work)
and I have a similar problem.)

My problem is iterating through my dictionary. It seems like it was much easier on Python 2. To solve it I casted my dictionary as a list, but then that causes problems because as I want to delete items from my dictionary, it leaves an empty list [] and confuses everything.

The part I stuggle with is:

```
node_list=list(graph[current_node])
cycle.append(node_list[0])
```

What I'm trying to do what would simply be, in python 2:

```
cycle.append(graph[current_node][0])
```

Graph is a dictionary.
When I later on delete the node: `del graph[current_node]` It remains as an empty list instead of just disappear. 
Is there a better way to do this?

I also do:

```
for i in range(len(path)):
    for key in graph.keys():
        if (''.join(path[i])) in (key):
            current_node=''.join(path[i])
            cycle=[current_node]
```

Instead of the more elegant (not too elegant, but I have low standards..):

```
for i in range(len(path)):
    if path[i] in graph:
        current_node = path[i]
        cycle = [current_node]
```

I know it makes sense that I could do the same thing in python 3 but it NEVER goes into the  `if path[i] in graph:` Maybe there's a different issue that I'm missing (probably)

This is "graph":

```
{'1': {'0'}, '0': {'3'}, '3': {'2'}, '2': {'1', '6'}, '5': {'4'}, '4': {'2'}, '7': {'9'}, '6': {'8', '5'}, '9': {'6'}, '8': {'7'}}
```

The key is the node and the items are the nodes that node goes to (So node 2 goes to nodes 1 and 6). When I say graph[current_node] I look for the node reachable by the current_node

Thank you!

Comment: What's `repr(graph)`?

Comment: @MikeGraham http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#repr

Comment: I don't think Mike is asking "what does `repr` do?", but rather, "what does `graph` look like when you display it with `repr(graph)`?"

Comment: I added that do the quesion

Comment: The code as posted fails because `visited` is undefined. It also seems suspicious that `visited` is read from but never written to. Is there more code you have omitted?

Comment: Yes, visited is simply a dictionary similar to graph, but the items are a count of how many nodes a key reaches. So it's 1 for most of them, but in the case where there are a node that goes to 2 nodes, the number will be 2

Comment: I added the entire code. The input is in this form: '0 -> 3
1 -> 0
2 -> 1,6
3 -> 2
4 -> 2
5 -> 4
6 -> 5,8
7 -> 9
8 -> 7
9 -> 6'

Comment: The second version does not work for me in Python 2.7. It reports `TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing` What version of Python 2 does it work in?

Comment: I think the Python 2 version expects a different data structure as input, and that's why it doesn't work for me. Is that right?

Comment: @Weeble - that's actually the same, I added the main so that it'd be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think you've made some mistakes in attempting to adapt the program to Python 3, so I'm going to go back to the original that you linked and highlight what needs to be changed to work in Python 3 and why.

In [line 63](https://github.com/jschendel/bioinformatics-algorithms-coursera/blob/5cf4cb8b8184534152bb2ebb92e13766d60773e0/Assignment_04E.py#L63):

```
edges[int(edge[0])] = map(int,edge[1].split(','))
```

In Python 2, `map` returns a list. In Python 3, `map` returns an object that is iterable but not indexable. So when you later try to index into it, you get an exception. (`TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`) The fix is to convert the iterable into a list:

```
edges[int(edge[0])] = list(map(int,edge[1].split(',')))
```

Your Python 3 version looks quite different and ends up producing sets instead of lists.

The other thing that does not work is this in [line 37](https://github.com/jschendel/bioinformatics-algorithms-coursera/blob/5cf4cb8b8184534152bb2ebb92e13766d60773e0/Assignment_04E.py#L37):

```
current_node =edge_dict.keys()[0]
```

In Python 2, `.keys()` returns a list. In Python 3, it returns a view object. You can fix this the same way:

```
current_node = list(edge_dict.keys())[0]
```

Your adaptation doesn't do the same thing:

```
for key in graph.keys():
    current_node=key[0]
```

This iterates through all the keys in your graph, which are strings. For each one, it sets current_node to be the first character in the key string! So by the end of the loop, current_node is equal to the first character from the string identifying an arbitrary node, which is not what you want at all.

The other issues are trivial. In Python 3 you need to replace `xrange` with `range`, which you've got fine, and change print statements to print function calls.

Answer (score 0):

> Graph is a dictionary. When I later on delete the node: `del graph[current_node]` It remains as an empty list instead of just disappear.

You're probably misinterpretting what you're seeing. Consider posting an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

> ```
> node_list=list(graph[current_node])`
> cycle.append(node_list[0])`
> ```
>
> What I'm trying to do what would simply be, in python 2:
>
> ```
> cycle.append(graph[current_node][0])
> ```

You haven't told us what `graph[current_node]` is. What kind of object is it?

Comment: I added it in the quesion